# plt.colorbar ticks unequal between plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

I am using matplotlib to plot heat maps, as below:

[image]

Note that the ticks on the colorbars differ. I want both of them to start at 0 and end at 1. I think the issue lies on the minimum values of each array (x_array is plotted on the left, and y_array on the right):

```
np.min(x_array)
0.10800000000000001
np.min(y_array)
4.679256262324e-310
```

(full arrays are shown below)

However, I am using the same specification for ticks in both plots:

```
plt.colorbar(ticks = np.linspace(0, 1, num = 5))
```

Any help with fixing this appreciated.

I am using Python 2.7 on Jupyter. Full code and arrays are:

```
plt.figure(figsize = (12,5))
plt.subplots_adjust(left= 0, right= 1, top = .9, bottom = 0.1, wspace = 0.001)
ticks = np.arange(0, 1, step = 0.1)

# left plot
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.xticks(ticks), plt.yticks(ticks)
plt.imshow(x_array, cmap=plt.cm.gray, origin = "lower", extent = (0,.9,0,.9))
plt.colorbar(ticks = np.linspace(0, 1, num = 5))

# right plot
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.xticks(ticks), plt.yticks(ticks)
plt.imshow(y_array, cmap=plt.cm.gray, origin = "lower", extent = (0,.9,0,.9))
plt.colorbar(ticks = np.linspace(0, 1, num = 5))

 x_array
 (array([[1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   ],
    [1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   ],
    [0.64 , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   ],
    [0.37 , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   ],
    [0.27 , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   ],
    [0.21 , 0.47 , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   ],
    [0.17 , 0.36 , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   ],
    [0.108, 0.29 , 0.46 , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   ],
    [0.108, 0.24 , 0.37 , 0.52 , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   , 1.   ]]),

 y_array
 array([[1.00000000e-002, 1.00000000e-002, 1.00000000e-002,
     1.00000000e-002, 1.00000000e-002, 1.00000000e-002,
     1.00000000e-002, 1.00000000e-002, 4.67925626e-310],
    [4.67925626e-310, 1.00000000e-002, 1.00000000e-002,
     1.00000000e-002, 1.00000000e-002, 1.00000000e-002,
     1.00000000e-002, 1.00000000e-002, 1.00000000e-002],
    [1.00000000e+000, 4.67925626e-310, 1.00000000e-002,
     1.00000000e-002, 1.00000000e-002, 1.00000000e-002,
     1.00000000e-002, 1.00000000e-002, 1.00000000e-002],
    [1.00000000e+000, 1.00000000e-002, 4.67925626e-310,
     1.00000000e-002, 1.00000000e-002, 1.00000000e-002,
     1.00000000e-002, 1.00000000e-002, 1.00000000e-002],
    [1.00000000e+000, 1.00000000e-002, 1.00000000e-002,
     4.67925626e-310, 1.00000000e-002, 1.00000000e-002,
     1.00000000e-002, 1.00000000e-002, 1.00000000e-002],
    [1.00000000e+000, 1.00000000e+000, 1.00000000e-002,
     1.00000000e-002, 4.67925626e-310, 1.00000000e-002,
     1.00000000e-002, 1.00000000e-002, 1.00000000e-002],
    [1.00000000e+000, 1.00000000e+000, 1.00000000e-002,
     1.00000000e-002, 1.00000000e-002, 4.67925626e-310,
     1.00000000e-002, 1.00000000e-002, 1.00000000e-002],
    [1.00000000e+000, 1.00000000e+000, 1.00000000e+000,
     1.00000000e-002, 1.00000000e-002, 1.00000000e-002,
     4.67925626e-310, 1.00000000e-002, 1.00000000e-002],
    [1.00000000e+000, 1.00000000e+000, 1.00000000e+000,
     1.00000000e+000, 1.00000000e-002, 1.00000000e-002,
     1.00000000e-002, 4.67925626e-310, 1.00000000e-002]]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to explicitely specify `vmin` for the left plot:

```
plt.imshow(x_array, cmap=plt.cm.gray, origin = "lower", extent = (0,.9,0,.9), vmin=0)
```

See https://matplotlib.org/2.1.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html for details.